# I want to create (or fork) an aggregated 'subset' of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is made up of rows that represent every play from several football games and I am simply calculating and aggregating the data so that I can do logistic regression on 2 data features... and a final feature that is just a W/L column.  Makes sense right? Nothing too snazzy for you experienced developers.

I already have all three of my aggregated columns available to view, but I can't seem to get them into ONE smaller dataframe with just 3 columns - Don't need the rest of the columns for this exercise.

```
Total_Score = (NFLDataFrame.groupby(["gameid","off"]).offscore.max()) - (NFLDataFrame.groupby(["gameid","off"]).defscore.max())
Total_Score_boolean = Total_Score > 0
Win_Loss = Total_Score_boolean.replace({True:"Win", False:"Loss"})
```

How do I get the Win_Loss into it's own NEW dataframe?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `Win_Loss` a series? Just use `Win_Loss = Win_Loss.to_frame()`

Comment: Add `NFLDataFrame.head(5)` please

Comment: Bharath, my Jupyter notebook will not allow me to copy-paste the output contents without getting really messy.  I can copy my input fine - but not output...